# firefox44.01 doesnot support to webdriver 2.51

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

Getting below error while executing selenium webdriver(2.51 )scripts in firefox44:
webdriver can able to open the browser but not an empty browser with url :
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0.2/firstrun/learnmore/

can anyone please help me out.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ranjans\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5188298946682853621webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1455279332288   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\cranjans\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5188298946682853621webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1455279332288   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1455279332289   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1455279332289   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1455279332289   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1455279332289   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1455279332290   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\cranjans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous5188298946682853621webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1455279330232,"mt":1455279330062}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0.2","st":1455258340685,"mt":1455258340500}}}
1455279332291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1455279332291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1455279332292   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1455279332292   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\cranjans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous5188298946682853621webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.45.0","st":1455279330232,"mt":1455279330062}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"44.0.2","st":1455258340685,"mt":1455258340500}}}
1455279332293   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1455279332299   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1455279332299   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1455279332299   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1455279332299   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1455279332300   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1455279332300   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1455279332304   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1455279332305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1455279332305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1455279332305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1455279332305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1455279332305   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1455279332384   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\cranjans\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5188298946682853621webdriver-profile\extensions.json
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1455279332479   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1455279332479   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1455279332479   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1455279332580   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1455279332580   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1455279332581   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1455279332645   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1455279332645   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1455279332645   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
```

Comment: Your code, please? And, is any older FF version compatible with it? Just tried python selenium 2.51.1 with FF 44.0.2 - works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of new issue of selenium. You need to `setPreference` as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` and then have to pass it in selenium object.

Below is the code which working fine for me. Take a reference of same

```
    WebDriver driver = null;
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("YOUR URL");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, all you need to do, to get it to work is to stop using the native navigate event in Firefox, and make a JavascriptExecutor that will navigate the page.  Then, you will see that it will work.   If you want to use that native navigate event, you need to downgrade to [Firefox 31.6.0 ESR](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/31.6.0esr/).  You can try a later version of ESR, but I suspect it wont work for you either.